# .htaccess redirect a folder in subdomain to a folder in main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here's what I need.

I need to redirect (301) all content of `blog.example.com/sample/` to `example.com/sample/` and I'd like to accomplish this using htaccess.

Here's what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com/sample [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.example\.com/sample/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com/sample [NC]`

Here having `/sample` is problematic because `HTTP_HOST` only matches host name part in a request so it will never match this condition.

You can use this rule instead:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.(example\.com)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^sample/ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Like a charm, it works. Gracias.